# Excel Macro - pull cell function until the end of the table

Tags: excel, vba

I will use an example to illustrate my question:

I have many tables which their lines quantity is different.
I want to pull down the function until the end of the table.

For example:

```
A        B
1        =1*2   // <- this is the function that I want to pull
2
3
4
```

The output should be:

```
A        B
1        =1*2
2        =2*2
3        =3*2
4        =4*2
```

It is important that the pull length is determined by the last cell at column A (in this case it is 4)

Please also note that the function may be changed either, this should work for any function.

Thank you,

Doron

Comment: Still uncertain what you are looking for here because based on that outline you could just use an in cell function of `=A1 * 2` and drag down but I feel your example is very simplistic and you are hoping to accomplish a more complex task.

Comment: Try recording a macro and then editing the code produced.  If you run into problems then post back with the code.

Comment: @engineersmnky - I need macro

Comment: @TimWilliams the problem is that when recording macro you can't define the end of the table (last cell). and my macro supposed to work on different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a macro that will autofill the value from cell `B1` to the end of the column to the left of it (in this case column `A`).

```
Sub AutoFill()
    Dim FillFrom As Range
    Set FillFrom = ActiveSheet.Range("B1")

    FillFrom.AutoFill Destination:=Range(FillFrom.Address, FillFrom.Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Address)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Public Sub DoWhatIWantYouToDo()
    Dim lr As Integer, i As Integer
    lr = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 2 To lr
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Formula = "=" & " A" & i & "*2"
    Next
End Sub
```